# How can I get Panelizer to link my panels to a specific URL instead of the Content option?

Tags: media, navigation, panels

[image]

This is the page that is shown when I configure a panel. How do I link the image to some other page than the content page? I am using Drupal 7. I think this question would benefit others who wish to link their images to other URLs when using Panelizer. I tried using the panels image link module, but I couldn't find any documentation and it didn't seem to do much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that I can make a user-uploaded image linkable to a fixed location that I choose. If I create a view that takes in the user-uploaded picture, and then add a link through views, Panelizer will let me place the view in a pane. This means I can have a linkable image in a pane. I have included step-by-step pictures.

[image]

This shows up upon the creation of a view. Click the add button by the fields in the left column to add the picture from a content type.

[image]

This shows you that a content node needs to be picked. In this case, it is a picture that the user uploads

[image]

Upon the selection of the picture views will ask how to display it. I have selected "Output as a link" This will then open up this part of the menu:

[image]

Here you can select the URL you want the link to go to. For example, somewhere on your site or to drupal.org :)

[image]

You then need to save everything. Then, go back to panelizer, or panels. There select a cog wheel and add content. This page should look like this: 
[image]

Then, it will bring up a window where you will need to click on the views option:

[image]

Then you should see these windows:

[image]
[image]